# Difference between creating a class and using a list for a stack?

Tags: python

I don't understand the difference between just using a list and appending and popping from it or creating a class which does the same thing?

```py
list = []
list.append(1)
list.append(2)
```

```py
class myStack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.container = []  # You don't want to assign [] to self - when you do that, you're just assigning to a new local variable called `self`.  You want your stack to *have* a list, not *be* a list.

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.size() == 0   # While there's nothing wrong with self.container == [], there is a builtin function for that purpose, so we may as well use it.  And while we're at it, it's often nice to use your own internal functions, so behavior is more consistent.

     def push(self, item):
         self.container.append(item)  # appending to the *container*, not the instance itself.

     def pop(self):
         return self.container.pop()  # pop from the container, this was fixed from the old version which was wrong

     def peek(self):
         if self.isEmpty():
             raise Exception("Stack empty!")
         return self.container[-1]  # View element at top of the stack

     def size(self):
         return len(self.container)  # length of the container

     def show(self):
         return self.container  # display the entire stack as list


s = myStack()
s.push('1')
s.push('2')
```

It looks the same to me so wouldn't the first code be a better implementation of a stack?

Comment: The better option isn't listed. Use a `deque`. That being said see the other comments. A `list` is a class, but if this is for academic, then they are trying to show you how classes work and the importance of them.

Comment: I am no expert, but a list is also just a class in python. The reason to implement a new class might just be to learn it or to add methods that the class of `list` does not have.

Comment: The first code is indeed better. My assumption though is that the second code is an academic exercise in OOP or data structures.

Comment: The difference is that the first one isn't a stack. You can modify a `list` in ways that are not valid for a stack, like  `list.pop(-2)`. You might want to use a class specifically because it **enforces** the stack interface...